# Rigify error for simple Human

Tags: rigify

I am trying to RIGIFY a human model with a BASIC HUMAN (META-RIG). When I select RIGIFY, the RIG becomes incredible small and it is not even a proper rig. I do receive the attached error. I have not deleted any bones.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Does anyone how to fix this please?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you apply the scale to the armature after scaling it to fit your model? - In Object mode, select the armature and hit Ctrl-A > Scale.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

It seems that you get the same error as [Rigify Generate Rig Error Index 0 Out of Range 2.83](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193315/rigify-generate-rig-error-index-0-out-of-range-2-83?rq=1).

blr's answer should help you

Comment: This worked. Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: If it worked for you, don't hesitate to accept my answer and marked the question as solved.

Comment: @user2770097 Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: @Squelletton Please don't quote other users answers to avoid duplication and scattering information